# Jekyll Now blog text align

Tags: css, jekyll, text-alignment, kramdown

How can I make a text justified in `Jekyll Now` in the simplest way? I have tried `{: .text-justify}`, but isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're half the way.

You're using an [Inline Attribute Lists (IAL)](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#inline-attribute-lists) in order to add attributes to an html element.

```
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus ...
{: .my-class}
```

This will add a `.my-class` class to the paragraph.

```
<p class="my-class">Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus …</p>
```

Now, you just have to add a corresponding [cascading style sheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) rule for this class.

```
.my-class{
   text-align: justify;
}
```

**Important note**: one accessibility best practice is to [avoid justified text](http://www.accessiq.org/news/news-features/2015/08/text-justification-and-accessibility).